# iPhone 8 proximity sensor not working after display switch

Tags: iphone, display, hardware, repair

so I've changed a splintered display including a new flex-cable with front camera, brightness and proximity sensor of an iPhone 8 for my first time and it is working nearly as wanted... nearly!

The proximity sensor does not work anymore but everything else: The front camera, the display, the home button, the automatic setting of brightness and also the earpice is working without a problem. The sensor is plugged in its place and can "see" through the cut-out.

My question is: Is there any step missing? Do I (which I doubt) have to activate again because it is a new hardware component?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

No, you don’t need to take any further steps. There are no additional settings for the proximity-sensor. I see only this steps to repaire your sensor:

- [Restarting](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559) your iPhone
- Trie to [restoring from a backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184)
- Trie to [restoring to factory-settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252)
- The proximity-sensor is malfunction (already delivered defective, or by assembling), so change the display again with a new one

If no step is helpful, I would advise to contact the apple support and make a appointment to show the iPhone bug.